# How can I release UIimage which was fetched from ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, release, alassetslibrary

I spent my whole 2weeks for just trying to resolve this problem. So frustrate!

Following 2 functions are what I'm using for fetching a image from device library.
If I use "setImage" function multiple times I keep losing my free memory on my iOS Device.

I think "**[imageFromAsset initWithCGImage:[[myasset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]];**" in assetImage function causes the problem.

Can any guys help me? Any clues or thinking would be SUPER appreciate! Please!

```
- (void)setImage:(NSURL *)imageURL{
UIImage *imageFromDeviceLibrary = [[UIImage alloc] init];
[[DevicePhotoControl sharedInstance] assetImage:[imageURL absoluteString] imageToStore:imageFromDeviceLibrary];    
UIImageView *fullImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageFromDeviceLibrary];
[imageFromDeviceLibrary release];
[self.view addSubview:fullImageView];
[fullImageView release];
}

- (void)assetImage:(NSString *)assetURL imageToStore:(UIImage *)imageFromAsset{
    // Handling exception case for when it doesn't have assets-library
if ([assetURL hasPrefix:@"assets-library:"] == NO) {
    assetURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"assets-library:",assetURL];
}
__block BOOL busy = YES;

ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
//get image data by URL
ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{
    [imageFromAsset initWithCGImage:[[myasset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]];
    busy = NO;
};
ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
{
    NSLog(@"Library Image Fetching Failed : %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
    busy = NO;
};
[assetslibrary assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:assetURL]
               resultBlock:resultblock
              failureBlock:failureblock];

while (busy == YES) {
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The moment the AssetLibrary is released, all the asset object will be gone with it.

I suggest that you create your assetLibrary in the app delegate to keep it alive and only reset it when you receive change notification ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification from the ALAssetLibrary

[here](http://www.openradar.me/10484334)

It may help you.

Comment: Thank Girish very much! Okay I'm gonna try it now and let you know!

Comment: I'm wondering when ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification is triggered?

Comment: You needs to add the notification as well as remove the notification.

Comment: I did it to my "-(id)init" function. I mean I added notification observer to above function. But It's not being triggered.

Comment: please click on link which I have added now in my answer if you are working on iOS 5.

Comment: NO, I'm not working on iOS5 but iOS6. I read it from other post which is saying that there's some bug about it on iOS5.

Comment: And I changed [DevicePhotoControl sharedInstance] this code. So I'm using not just normal way. init and release for this. But even I release this function I couldn't get back my memory. @Girish I really appreciate taking your important time on this problem.

Comment: try to work it on iOS less than 5.0 & let me know your feedback.

Comment: Thanks Girish! Here is weekend. I will try it on next Monday!

Comment: Hi Girish. I couldn't try your suggestion because my iPad version is 6.x so to test I need to revert it but I think it will take much time. So I decided not to do it. And I found one clue which might be the solution for this problem. My problem was the free memory is continually decreased whenever I use assetLibrary. But I also tested with some example codes which use this assetLibrary. Those are provided by apple. I was able to see that same thing happened on this sample codes too. I think this is naturally working of this Library.